# json_decode returning NULL with valid JSON data

Tags: php, json, validation

This is a snippet of code inside my JSON parser function, which is working fine with about a dozen or so various JSON files:

*The prints are there for current debugging purposes*

```
    $this->response = stripslashes($this->response);
    print_r($this->response);
    $this->response = json_decode($this->response);
    print_r($this->response);
```

The first print gives me the JSON string, and the second print gives me null. Using `json_last_error` I managed to find out that PHP was refusing to parse the JSON as it was in an invalid syntax.

This is a snipped of the JSON I'm parsing ([full thing here](http://pastebin.com/EXshG0NG)), it validates with every validator I can find on Google:

```
{
"success": 1,
"stores": [
    {
        "name": "Winton",
        "address": "370-374 , Wimborne Road, Bournemouth, Dorset BH92HE",
        "telephone": "",
        "email": "info@99pstoresltd.com",
        "website": "",
        "description": "Mon  - 09.00-18.00  Tue - 09.00-18.00  Wed - 09.00-18.00  Thu - 09.00-18.00  Fri - 09.00-18.00  Sat - 09.00-18.00  Sun - 10.00-16.00",
        "lat": "50.7413",
        "lng": "-1.87926",
        "titlewebsite": "Website",
        "titleemail": "Email",
        "titletel": "Telephone",
        "titlecontactstore": "Contact this store",
        "titlekm": "km",
        "titlemiles": "miles",
        "cat_name": "",
        "cat_img": "",
        "img": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Boscombe",
        "address": "The Sovereign Centre, Boscombe, Bournemouth, Dorset BH14SX",
        "telephone": "",
        "email": "info@99pstoresltd.com",
        "website": "",
        "description": "Mon  - 08.00-18.00  Tue - 08.00-18.00  Wed - 08.00-18.00  Thu - 08.00-18.00  Fri - 08.00-18.00  Sat - 08.00-18.00  Sun - 10.00-16.00",
        "lat": "50.7272",
        "lng": "-1.83952",
        "titlewebsite": "Website",
        "titleemail": "Email",
        "titletel": "Telephone",
        "titlecontactstore": "Contact this store",
        "titlekm": "km",
        "titlemiles": "miles",
        "cat_name": "",
        "cat_img": "",
        "img": ""
    }]
}
```

I have no idea why this isn't parsing as the JSON looks fine to me! Been staring at this for quite a while now so would be more than happy to here some thoughts on this.

**EDIT:**
Copy and pasting the data from the first print_r and pushing it through the json_decode works fine. I'm assuming this means there is an issue with where the JSON is originating from which could be messing up encoding or something?

Comment: Don't know why I didn't try before but it also parses fine for me too if I use the data in the pastebin. However, this is the exact same data that the first print_r gives me (I copy and pasted that pastebin from that print_r). Does this mean it's an encoding issue of some sort?

Comment: Parses fine for me as well, did you check possible encoding issues? Why are you running stripslashes?

Comment: I attempted to use `iconv()` to ensure that the string was in UTF-8 format, but I'm not sure how to actually check that the encoding is correct (My client doesn't have access to the server code giving me this json response).

The stripslashes was put in there to accommodate some of the other JSON strings that pass through the function, I have removed the stripslashes but am left with the same problem.

Comment: @jackmullen If you are given valid JSON-formatted data, it is by definition UTF-8 and any escape sequences would already be applied in the JSON.  You simply need to `json_decode()` it.

Comment: @MikeBrant The server code that is serving me the JSON is using json_encode() (that is all I really know about how/what is being sent to me), so in that case the JSON should be in the correct format and encoding? The `json_decode()` is still giving me a null value however.

Comment: @jackmullen Well have you verified that you are actually getting the expected response from whatever method you are using to contact the source server?

Comment: @MikeBrant yes, the server gives me the expected response through my other various functions. The valid JSON that I posted in the pastebin is from the `print_r($this->response);` immediately **before** the `json_encode()`, so I know that the data from the server is what I'm expecting.

Comment: Can you just echo to html to check?     echo htmlentities($this->response);     and either paste the html source code into jsfiddle.net OR paste the browser rendered string into another pastebin?

Comment: @JosephShih Here is a jsfiddle of that `echo htmlentities($this->response);` result. https://jsfiddle.net/0j08go6s/
**Edit:** This resulting html also works fine when passed through my encoding code above

Comment: It's very strange, even using JavaScript's JSON.parse method it also works. See the added javascript to verify first store's name here https://jsfiddle.net/0j08go6s/1/ It alerts perfectly fine.

Comment: @JosephShih Yes, very strange indeed. I even tried using `htmlentities($this->response); ` and then `html_entity_decode($this->response);` and I'm still getting a null value from the `json_decode()`.

Comment: What does `json_last_error_msg` return?

Comment: `json_last_error()` gives me `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

`json_decode($this->response, true);`

**From the documentation about the second parameter**:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

*Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php*